# Copy only final text from track changes in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document with track changes enabled. I want to copy part of the text as it appears when the document is set to render as "Final", and I want to paste the text into a plain text editor. When I try this, my pasted plain text includes all of the text, even deletions from the prior draft. How can I directly copy text from Word to a text editor without the deleted text appearing in the plain text copy?

I can make this work by making a copy of the document and accepting all changes, but then it's harder to identify the relevant portions of the text.

(I'm using Word for Mac 2011.)
This is similar to the question ["Copy and paste without tracked changes in MS Office 2013"](https://superuser.com/questions/895997/copy-and-paste-without-tracked-changes-in-ms-office-2013), but neither of the answers work for me, perhaps due to differences in the version of Word.

[Edited to clarify that I want to copy directly from Word to the text editor.]

Answer (score 0):

Just combine your two attempts:

- copy only the desired text to a new Word document
- accept all changes
- copy the text to the editor